# Beautiful soup cannot extract HTML from pages when opening links from a file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have some web links in a file, `article_links.txt`, which I want to open one by one, extract their text, and print them out. My code to do this is:

```
import requests
from inscriptis import get_text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = open(r'C:\Users\h473\Documents\Crawling\article_links.txt', "r")

for a in links:
    print(a)
    page = requests.get(a)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    html = soup.find(class_='article-wrap')
    if html==None:
        html = soup.find(class_='mag-article-wrap')

    text = get_text(html.text)

    print(text)
```

But I get an error saying, `--->     text = get_text(html.text)`

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

So, when I printed out the `soup` variable to see what ts contents are. This is what I find for each link:

```
http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>Bad Request</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/></head>
<body><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr/><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</body></html>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>Bad Request</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/></head>
<body><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr/><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</body></html>
```

So, I tried to extract the text from the links individually, like so:

```
import requests
from inscriptis import get_text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
html = soup.find(class_='article-wrap')
if html==None:
    html = soup.find(class_='mag-article-wrap')
text = get_text(html.text)
print(text)
```

And it works perfectly! So, I tried to give the links in a list/array form, and tried to extract the text from each of them:

```
import requests
from inscriptis import get_text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = ['http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law',
'http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42946/Type/eDaily/India-M-A-deals-brewing-in-insurance-sector',
'http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42947/Type/eDaily/China-Online-insurance-premiums-soar-31-in-1Q2018',
'http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42948/Type/eDaily/South-Korea-Courts-increasingly-see-65-as-retirement-age',
'http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Magazine/ReadMagazineArticle/aid/40847/Creating-a-growth-environment-for-health-insurance-in-Asia']

#open(r'C:\Users\h473\Documents\Crawling\article_links.txt', "r")

for a in links:
    print(a)
    page = requests.get(a)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    html = soup.find(class_='article-wrap')
    if html==None:
        html = soup.find(class_='mag-article-wrap')

    text = get_text(html.text)

    print(text)
```

And this works perfectly too! So, what goes wrong when pulling the links from the text file? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your URLs are invalid, because they all end with a newline. You can see the same thing like this:

```
>>> page = requests.get('http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law\n')
>>> page
<Response [400]>
>>> page.text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

BeautifulSoup is parsing that HTML just fine. It's just not very useful HTML. And, in particular, it doesn't have anything with class `article-wrap` or class `mag-article-wrap`, so both of your `find` return `None`. And you don't have any error handling for that case; you just try to use the `None` value as if it were an HTML element, hence the exception.

You should have noticed this from printing out each `a`: there's an extra blank line after each line. That either means that there are newline characters in the strings (which is what's actually happening), or that there are blank lines between the actual lines (which would be an even more invalid URL—you'd get a `ConnectionError` or some subclass of it).

---

What you want to do is simple: just strip the newlines off each line:

```
for a in links:
    a = a.rstrip()
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what in your file. But in my opinion, there may have a new empty line in your file that causing the `NoneType` object

Answer (score -4):

Try :

```
with f open("sample.txt"):
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? And you didn't even format the code properly.